# Nesting array in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am working with the movie API, and in Angular service i have two calls. One for movie list and one for genres list. In controller i assigned that array to '$scope.movies' and '$scope.genres'. Movie array have nested array 'genres_id[]'. Id in 'movies.genres_id' is the same as id in genres array. Genres array have also property 'genres.name'. Now my question is it possible link these two arrays with id and how if it is? In my html i have lopp through movie array

```
ng-repeat="movie in movies"
```

now i would like display title from movie array and genre from genre name.Is it possible? I hope i wrote this understandable, thanks

movie list

[image: movie list]

genres list

[image: genres list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must work (check for typos).

First add this function to your controller:

```
/**
 * Returns the *first* Object in an Array with property with a given value
 * @param array: the array in which we search
 * @param property: the name of the property to search for
 * @param value: the value that the given property must have 
 * @returns {*}
 */
    $scope.getObjectWithPropertyValue = function (array, property, value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i][property] == value) {
                return array[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

you can use it in other cases too.

Next in your view you can do:

```
<p ng-repeat="movie in movies">

    <h3>{{movie.original_name}}</h3>
    <span>{{movie.overview}}</span>

    <h5>Genres</h5>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="gen_id in movie.genre_ids">
            {{getObjectWithPropertyValue(genres, 'id', gen_id).name}}
        </li>
    </ul>

</p>
```

Also if you provide the actual datasets and not just an image i can give you a working example in jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you Christos, it works! thanks again and i apologize i will learn better use stack overflow.

Comment: @userDC it's ok. also i highly recommend that you start using a library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs). It's will save you a lot of time and make your code run faster. If you used lodash i could write the function i gave you in one line.

Comment: Definetly i will check lodash, thank you. I am beginner in programming and i don't know tricks, hacks for better approach and i am really thankful when i get usefull answers from experts like you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily about *nesting* arrays.

- Display title from movie:

  ```
  {{movie.title}}
  ```
- Display genre name:

  ```
  {{genre[movie.genre_id].name}}
  ```

As you notice, your best option is to transform genre array to an object indexed by movie *genre_id*. Otherwise you would have to define a function `getGenre` that returns the genre given a movie *genre_id*:

```
    {{getGenre(movie.genre_id).name}}  // prefer the solution above so as to 
                                       // not evaluate the function on every digest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the proper genre in you controller using http://underscorejs.org/#find.

For example: var item = _.find($scope.genres, function(genre) { genre.id === movie.id });